# handlesubmit is undefined when i am writing the code in react functional component

Tags: reactjs, forms

heres the code for the register component in which i have written using react functional components. what am i missing ,react states? the code is below.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './Register.css'
import axios from 'axios'

function Register() {
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState(''); 
const [password, setPassword] = useState(''); 
const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState(''); 

     const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = {name , email, password, confirmPassword};
     
        console.log('data');
       
     }
     
    return (
        <div className="signup__container">

            <div className="signup__containerInfo">
            <h1 className="h1__swari">सवारी नविकरणको लागि</h1>
            <hr />
            </div>


<form4 onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<h5 className="h5__form"> Name</h5>
<input type="text" placeholder="पुरा नाम लेख्नुहोस्"  value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}/>
<h5 className="h5__form"> Email-Address </h5>
<input type="Email" placeholder="ईमेल लेख्नुहोस्" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
<h5 className="h5__form"> Password </h5>
<input type="Password" placeholder="पासवर्ड लेख्नुहोस्s" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
<h5 className="h5__form"> Confirm Password </h5>
<input type="Password" placeholder="पुन: पासवर्ड लेख्नुहोस्" value={confirmPassword} onChange={e => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)} />
<p>
<button type="submit" className="signup__registerButton" >Register Now</button>
</p>
</form4>
        </div>
    )
    }

export default Register
```

I think all the code is good but only the handle submit says error. i am new to react pls help.

Comment: Not only you missing state, there is no such HTML element `form4`

Comment: Are you directly mutating states rather than letting React take care of it??

Comment: Please define  `const [name,setName] = useState('');` and then  `onChange={e=>setName(e.target.value)}`. Otherwise you are mutating the states which is not the practice.

Comment: there are multiple forms i tired to give them a number

Comment: @Ankush Verma i added as u told still getting same error. can you show the coded solution would be great help!.

Comment: @AnkushVerma i am not mutating the states

Comment: i have updated the code.

Comment: `const data={name , email, password,confirmPassword}`

Comment: i am unable to print the values to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Line 7 should be

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
```

Comment: no errors but i am not able to print the data in console which is the main objective of this program from the register form.